# Dynamic Query and Coparison of Bit DataType

Tags: sql-server, bit, dynamic-sql

I have a dynamic query that I use to retrieve a value that should be 1 or 0 (Bit DataType) (true or false).

This is the code block

```
DECLARE @Country VARCHAR(255) = (select param_value from [kat].[PARAMS] where param_name = 'Country')

DECLARE @CountrySelection AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @RESULT AS BIT

    set @CountrySelection ='select ['+@Country+'] from COUNTRY_BLOCKS where param_id = 1';


        EXEC sp_executesql @CountrySelection , N'@RESULT BIT OUTPUT',@RESULT =  @RESULT OUTPUT


        **if (CAST(@RESULT as BIT) = 1)
        BEGIN**
```

However, it sees that the @RESULT does not contain 1 or 0 and therefore the IF condition is never met. Is there a way to check the exact DataType of the returned value in the @RESULT.

On the other hand if you are aware of a better solution to get this functionality I would appreciate if you could share some ideas.

Many thanks in advance,

Kat

Comment: Hint: Use PRINT and print your countryselection statement and run it, to see what it takes for parameters and what the result is

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here at all. This won't work as posted because you don't have the @RESULT parameter in your query. Something in the design has gone very very wrong here. Once you have to resort to using dynamic sql to indicate which column to return it is a clear sign you need to rethink your process.